# How to plot graph in microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

I have very little understanding of excel, and I came to know we can plot graphs in excel.

I have one query that if I have below log

Function = "DumpSample", Msg = "internal_stats: Wed 2021-01-13 15:13:54 UTC", Val = 10
Function = "DumpSample", Msg = "internal_stats: Wed 2021-01-13 15:13:57 UTC", Val = 45
Function = "DumpSample", Msg = "internal_stats: Wed 2021-01-13 15:14:00 UTC", Val = 1
.... 1000's of more lines

How can I parse and plot the graph using time and value which and display using either bar or line chart or etc is for example:-

15:13:54, 10

15:13:57, 45

15:14:00, 1

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to transform the data before you can use the graph features

1. Paste the data into a column
2. Go to the *Data* tab of the ribbon
3. Hit the *Text to Columns* button
4. Select *Fixed Width*
5. Choose where you want the columns to be separated
6. Hit *Finish*

Now the data is transformed you can go to the *Insert* tab to find all the charting buttons